# Redirect to subdirectory and change its name

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, rename, subdirectory

I have a structure like this: http://example.com/mainshop/subshop/ I want to make it so subshop serves more than one customer. So it would load if someone visited

```
http://example.com/mainshop/cust1 or http://example.com/mainshop/cust2
```

But when they visit like that, I want the url to stay the same for all links in the subshop.

In mainshops .htaccess file, I have this

```
Rewritebase /mainshop/
RewriteRule ^(?:cust1|cust2)/? subshop/ [L,NC]
```

If one of the urls is entered, the url displays as I want. In the subshops .htaccess file, I have

```
Rewritebase /mainshop/subshop/
RewriteRule ^cust1/(.*) /subshop/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

I know the last line above won't cover all cases but I just want to get the basic part working for now.

The shop uses the parameters cid for categories and pid for products.

When someone visits http://example.com/mainshop/cust1/index.php?cid=3, for example, the url displays correctly and that category is displayed on the page.

All of the links for the products listed on that page are correct, like http://example.com/mainshop/cust1/product.php?cid=3&pid=4. When that link is clicked on, the url in the browsers url box displays that way. However, the page still loads the category page, not the product page as it should.

So the redirect works for the basic url and the categories but not the products, even though the url for the browser is correct.

Comment: `^(?:cust1|cust2)/?$` - you anchored this pattern to the end of the subject, by using the `$` at the end. But `cust1/index.php` _does not_ “end” after the `cust1/` part, so this rule does not match in this case.

Comment: Thank you. That solved a big part of it. I also realized I had to change the code in the php files to use the correct name in the url (like cust1). In the shop I have categories and products in those categories. If I click on a category, it displays the products in it. But if I then click on one of those products, it stays on the same page. I changed the rewrite in the subshops .htaccess file to RewriteRule ^cust1/(.*)$ subshop/$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,R=301] If I look at the url on the page, it is correct. Why would the rewrite work for the categories and not the products in them?

Comment: Please edit that new info into the question, without proper formatting in comments that is quite hard to read. And please also make clear, which .htaccess is located where exactly in the folder structure now. Plus an example of such a product page URL.

Comment: My question has been edited to make things clearer, I hope.